# What part can I use on a PCB for a potentiometer of this size?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, altium, potentiometer, pinout

I'm trying what female part to add on the PCB. I would also need the ECAD footprint model. Does anyone know what part to use and to find its footprint? Thanks[image]

Source: https://madpcb.com/glossary/variable-resistor/

I was looking for female headers like this one:

https://www.snapeda.com/parts/PPTC051LFBN-RC/Sullins%20Connector%20Solutions/view-part/?welcome=home

But I'm not even sure how to import this into Altium. Usually I would be provided with a library and schematic files but there is none with that website.

In Altium I want to wire the left audio and the right audio to a potentiometer and the middle pin of the potentiometer feeds to the LM386's input. I wasn't sure how to do this and looking for guidance.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Surface mount or through hole? Single or multi-turn? Power requirements? Trimmer adjustable or knob? There are hundreds of styles of PCB mountable potentiometers, so you have to be specific.  What do you mean by "female part"? The PCB footprint?  It's usually in the datasheet.  Try Digi-Key to narrow down your choices, then look for the datasheet and ECAD models.

Comment: the pins insert through holes in the PCB and are then soldered ... or, wires are wrapped around the pins and are soldered,  if the pot is panel mounted

Comment: Ok thanks I just created a footprint for the pads to mount my potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

> I just created a footprint for the pads to mount my potentiometer.

To do that, first select the pot to be used.  They come in a wide variety of sizes and styles. Top adjust or side adjust? For a 100 kΩ pot in what I assume is a relatively low-voltage application, power level probably isn't a critical factor.

Once you have selected one that is available, affordable, and meets your requirements, the datasheet will have a recommended footprint complete with dimensions.